# product of two variable in Google Optimization Tools python

Tags: or-tools

I have a optimization problem. The object is to max two variable x and y. How to represent it in google optimization tools python version.

what i can do  now is:

```
 from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
 solver = pywraplp.Solver('RunIntegerExampleCppStyleAPI',pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
 x=solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x')
 y=solver.Intvar(0,1,'y')
 objective = solver.Objective()
 #so how to get the object function of max x*y?
```

Answer (score 0):

The question I want to define is quadratic programming, so it can't be solved in linear programming.